# AnyLogic - Is there a function like "Move by Transporter to seized resource"?

Tags: anylogic

In this model I want to transport MaterialBoxes (Agent) to the next available workstation by an AGV. I wanted to keep the model as simple as possible, but I did not find a solution to transport the MaterialBoxes to a seized resource (Workstation 1 or Workstation 2) by using the "Move by Transporter" or "Seize Transporter" blocks. Therefore I adapted the solution of the "job shop model" (https://anylogic.help/tutorials/job-shop/index.html) by using the "rack pick" block to transport the Materialboxes from the rack to the seized workstation. How can I adapt the model and avoid the process step going through the rack system with "rackStore" and "rackPick"? And I still have the problem to allocate an AGV to transport the MaterialBoxes from Workstation 1 and Workstation 2 to the Exit. Currently I'm just using the "moveTo" block to transport the boxes without a transport resource to the Exit. I am grateful for any advice. Thank you very much.

[current Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K02LN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a custom variable to your agents where you can store the workstation that they seized and then in the move to block you can have them move to the station that they seized.

[image]

When the agent then seizes a workstation you save the work station it seized to the variable.

[image]

When it is time to move the agent you can move it to the location of the seized workstation.

[image]

You can also check out the solution in the example model Trauma Center https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/0c41592c-96d8-4824-b816-c89eccfd79db?mode=SETTINGS

Here agents move to the resource unit home, location of the unit that they seized

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I will try this. Thank you so much! Best regards Jan

Comment: Great! Glad I could help, let me know if it works and remember to accept the answer if you found it useful and upvote if you think it worthy ;-)